# WPF radcombobox: get values from multiple columns

Tags: wpf, vb.net, telerik

I have a radcombobox with 2 columns and need the value from the 2nd column.  I'm using this code to obtain the value in the dropdownclosed event:

```
                theValue = DirectCast(cboSheen.SelectedValue, System.Data.DataRowView).Row("pctUpcharge")
```

XAML:

```
                       <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cboSheen" FontSize="16" Margin="0,8,0,0" Background="#F6F8FA" BorderBrush="#D7D8DD" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Text="{Binding sheen}" TextSearch.TextPath="Sheen" IsEditable="True" Style="{DynamicResource RadComboBoxStyle3}" >
                            <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DataGridRow DataContext="{Binding}" Width="400">
                                        <DataGridRow.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Sheen}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding pctUpcharge}" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </DataGridRow.Template>
                                    </DataGridRow>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

This does the job almost 100% of the time but there are times when it bombs out with this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can immediately reselect the item from the combobox and the code will work OK.

So it appears that this line of code is not stable.  Is there a better way to get this value?

Thanks

Comment: Overriding the DataGridRow.Template defeats the purpose completely as you will no longer have any cells. Using the DataGridRow control outside of a DataGrid does not make any sense either for that matter.

Comment: Yes, I see your point.  I'm not sure why it was coded that way.  I changed the XAML to this (below), ran a few tests, and will see how it goes.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                  <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sheen}"></TextBlock>
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding pctUpcharge}"  Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>